# Auto Fill JAXB Class - Sample Request

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb

I am a consumer of a webservice. I have an XSD from an endpoint which generates hundreds of classes. In order to test a real request, it would be a good idea to send the full request to my webservice to see how it behaves. However, while creating this request can be manageable for a few classes (10 jaxb classes), the time to create a simulated request with hundreds increases substantially. To make a request from scratch, with all fields, it would roughly take 6K lines of code for one scenario.

I am considering using reflection to set values of a lot of these fields, with something like this:

```
ReflectionUtils.getAllMethods(vendorField,
            withModifier(Modifier.PUBLIC), withPrefix("get"), withAnnotation(annotation));
```

However, for hundreds of classes, even this method requires a boat load of work. Before I waste a lot of time, is there a better solution to making a huge request that is much more clean, concise and takes less to develop?

Comment: Would be good to have an XJC plugin which would add something like `generateValues(ValueGenerationStrategy)` to each of the schema-derived classes. You could then use some default strategy or define a custom strategy to random-generate and assign individual values. I even things this should be already more-or-less possible with the `Copyable` plugin from my [JAXB2-Basics](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/).

Comment: @lexicore might behoove of me to try that plugin out. but a strategy like you define would really be ideal. i might have to start a gitrepo for something useful

Comment: I lead the [JAXB2-Basic](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/) project which provides a set of useful XJC plugins. It would be actually quite easy to develop such a plugin analogous to the [`CopyablePlugin`](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/blob/master/basic/src/main/java/org/jvnet/jaxb2_commons/plugin/copyable/CopyablePlugin.java). We can team up on this.

Comment: @lexicore sounds good. I'll pull down your project in the next few days, understand it, and pm you so we can double team this. cheers.

Comment: I've given this a couple of thoughts and came to the conclusion that it would be better to use JAXB runtime model rather than generated code. A problematic case is randomization of collections or choices.